# How to select a deep learning algorithm

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

Can somebody share some light on how to choose a deep learning algorithm.

I have a specific flow chart i follow for machine learning, most of the times this give right results

[Click the link here](https://miro.medium.com/max/1600/1*dYgEs2roROf3j2ANzkDHMA.png)

I like to similar sort of diagrm for deep learning as well.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the problem and your skills. For example, image classification of airplanes or animals can be done with Deep Convolutional Neural network algorithms. Very easy to implement are the regression algorithms. A game can be programmed to win every time by using the Bellman reward functions. I would begin by reading some tutorials for Machine Learning such as https://github.com/WeizmannML/course2019. Good luck.